# Nested query error in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I get the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

when I try to run the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
 WHERE GroupID = 478 
   AND accountNo IN (
           SELECT TOP 5000 accountNo
             FROM (
               SELECT DISTINCT accountNo 
                 FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
                WHERE GroupID = 478
              )
       )
```

Currently, my query consists of a series of nested queries from a single table `tbl_usgGroupXref`. The table consists of multiple months of records for each account. The innermost query is to get the distinct accounts. The next outer query is to get any 5000 of those accounts (I couldn't seem to combine `TOP` with `DISTINCT`). And the outermost query is to get the count of the actual records represented by the 5000 accounts.

Could anyone shed some light on the error or revise this sql so that it works?

Comment: I believe you can get rid of the innermost query with `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5000 accountNo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to alias this subquery:

```
 FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT accountNo 
     FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
    WHERE GroupID = 478
  ) AS MySubQuery
```

Also to note, just saying `TOP 5000` isn't any guarantee that you'll get the *first* records.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the subquery to be so complex because the IN will ignore duplicates. DISTINCT isn't needed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
 WHERE GroupID = 478 
   AND accountNo IN (
           SELECT TOP 5000 accountNo
             FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
                WHERE GroupID = 478
       )
```

However, the `TOP 5000` is pointless because you have no ORDER BY so you have 5000 arbitrary rows.

Comment: Sorry, 'first' was imprecise - I was just looking for a random 5000. But note taken.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign an alias to most inner select as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
 WHERE GroupID = 478 
   AND accountNo IN (
           SELECT TOP 5000 accountNo
             FROM (
               SELECT DISTINCT accountNo 
                 FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
                WHERE GroupID = 478
              ) ALIAS
       )
```

**OR**

combine TOP and DISTINCT

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
 WHERE GroupID = 478 
   AND accountNo IN (
           SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5000 accountNo
           FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
           WHERE GroupID = 478
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also write:

```
       SELECT TOP 5000 accountNo
         FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT accountNo 
             FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
            WHERE GroupID = 478
          )
```

as:

```
       SELECT TOP 5000 accountNo
       FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
       WHERE GroupID = 478
       GROUP BY accountNo
```

---

and your whole query as:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM 
  ( SELECT TOP 5000 
          COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tbl_usgGroupXref 
    WHERE GroupID = 478
    GROUP BY accountNo
   ) grp
```